# HTML CSS text's last character starts a new line

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem where I need a div to grow according to the text that's inside it. The text is from a user's input so its dynamic and can contain new lines. So to sum it up:

- The div mustn't have `width:100%`
- The text must be wrapped in case of a very long word
- The text might contain new lines

A simple `white-space: pre-wrap;` and `word-break: break-word;` did the trick in most cases but the problem is that with some fonts (I'm using ionic so android uses 'Noto Sans Hebrew') the last character starts a new line.

I was able to narrow down the problem and create [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbwQBK)

I guess it might be an unexpected width of some characters, can anyone think of a fix or a workaround?

Comment: Divs behave like that naturally. Removing `word-break: break-word;` actually fixed it in your pen. I didn't try with other fonts.

Comment: Yes it would fix it but I must have `word-break: break-word;` since a user could enter a really long word and in that case the word will not be visible. Remember it runs on a web browser inside a smart phone so width is small

Comment: So the text that's inside the div is actually user input? You should add that to the question. You're more than likely going to have to make a compromise between allowing the user to scroll horizontally, breaking the word and using width: 100% or the element used to output the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out its an issue with that specific fonts. Somehow the characters' width isn't calculated correctly and most sentences end up with less width than they need.

Changing the font to OpenSans Hebrew (which looks the same) resolved this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

For this particular pen that you provided, removing either `white-space: pre-wrap;` 
 or `word-break: break-word;` fixes the issue as each of them cancels the effect of one-another. However, I recommend deleting your `white-space: pre-wrap`.

Keeping the `white-space: pre-wrap` will be as if we're saying "keep everything as in `white-space: normal` but do keep the whitespace coming from HTML literally"
As per [MDN specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at "br" tags, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Comment: But if the text contains a new line it will not be displayed